# Bootstrap Carousel Text only - issues with indicator position

Tags: css, bootstrap-carousel

I'm trying to make a carousel with just text in it. The carousel / slider is working good now and it's responsive as well. Now I am having some issues with the position of the indicators.

Here's [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydf5uuLm/) and my CSS code. Hope you can help me

```
#about .carousel-control{
  color: #2db4a0;
  background-image: none;
}

#about .carousel-indicators li{
  border: none;
  background-color: #424242;
}

#about .carousel-indicators .active{
  background-color: #2DB4A0;
}
```

As you can see, the indicators are in the text. How can I put them under the text. I am hoping for your help

Comment: I understand why you don't want the arrows to go over the text, but making them appear under the text will also cause issues. Maybe consider giving more paddings from the sides so the arrows can fit there?

Comment: Thanks for the fast respond but i meant the little dots under the carousel.

Comment: Updated my answer, there is also bottom indicator solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to remove side indicators from the text, move them left and right with margin. Add this code to your css file:

```
.carousel-inner>.item {
    margin: 0 50px;
}

left carousel-control {
    margin-left: -15px;
}

right carousel-control {
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

There are also queries, which change the indicators depends on resolution, that's why you need to play with values above under every query.

For bottom indicators add bottom-margin to body tag and since their position is absolute you need to push them more bottom:

```
body {
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: -30px;
}
```

Here is an updated project:
https://jsfiddle.net/ydf5uuLm/4/

Comment: Thank you for that helpful and fast respond. You solved my problem.